# How can you find all versions of the dotnet debugger (vsdbg)

Tags: c#, .net, vscode-debugger

Is it possible to get a list of versions of vsdbg? Microsoft seems to only provide a shell script to f.g. install it on some Linux host (f.e. Raspberry Pi).
But I would like to know all versions that are available maybe together with release notes or a change log. Does this exist?

Background: GLIBCXX version requirements have been bumped up on the latest version and it doesn't run on my target platform anymore. So the toolchain for linux-arm used for vsdbg is not compatible anymore.
I would like to at least find the latest version that works on the target platform.

Does anybody know a way to get a list of versions for this component?